# jQuery custom accordion with first div opens on the initial load - issues with modifying arrow images

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I couldn't find the answers on StackOverlow what I am experiencing. I referenced [Custom Accordion with arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950489/custom-accordion-with-arrows) to set up the initial accordion.

I am having difficulties making the image icon to change based on whether the hidden div is Show or Hide.

1. On the initial load, the first (div class="sectionContent") should be Open with an upper arrow image -- I am not able to change the arrow icon to be upper arrow.
2. The section header should toggle the hidden content and change the arrow image. -- I am not able to make this work. When I click on the section header whose hidden content is visible, arrow image doesn't change.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunflowersh/VfQHK/3/)

```
var headers = $('.sectionDown a');
var contentAreas = $('.sectionContent').hide();
var firstContentAreas = $('.sectionContent').hide().first().show();

headers.click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var panel = $(this).parent('div').next('div');
 var isOpen = panel.is(':visible');
 $('.sectionDown a').first().addClass('close');
 // open or close as necessary
 contentAreas.slideUp();
 panel[isOpen? 'slideUp': 'slideDown']()
  // trigger the correct custom event
  .trigger(isOpen? 'hide': 'show');
  $('.sectionDown a').removeClass('close');
  $(this).removeClass('close').addClass('close');

  // stop the link from causing a pagescroll
  return false;
 });
```

Comment: just add or remove classes that contain the arrow image as a background-image relative to the click function and your current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/GHLM9/

```
headers.click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var panel = $(this).parent('div').next('div');
    var isOpen = panel.is(':visible');
    // open or close as necessary
    contentAreas.slideUp();
    panel[isOpen ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']()
    // trigger the correct custom event
    .trigger(isOpen ? 'hide' : 'show');
    $('.sectionDown a').not(this).removeClass('close');
    $(this).toggleClass('close');

    // stop the link from causing a pagescroll
    return false;
});
```